# How to make a contributed Eclipse command key binding configurable?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm assigning a key binding to my command in the plugin.xml:

```
  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key commandId="MyCommand"
             contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
             schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
             sequence="M1+R"/>
  </extension>
```

It works, but it doesn't show up in Preferences > Keys and therefore the user can't change it. How can I make it configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a command is filtered out from the key configuration preference page, unless it is categorized.

You can either disable this filtering using the "well-hidden" filter button on the bottom half of the Key configuration dialog, or you can define a category for your command.